# Absolute and relative path in linux for process image

Tags: linux, bash

I'm learning Linux and I have a bit of a hard time understanding the file system. I've stumbled upon a question that gives me Process with PID 4433 and tells me that I need to find relative and absolute path to that process image.
It also tells, that currently, we are in folder /home/admin.

I don't understand the question, as this last info confuses me. I thought that /home/admin was a separate directory from /proc/, where processes are stored if I am correct? How do you get that on top of /home/admin?
And which part of that folder is considered to be process image? What are some useful things you can do with this?

Thank you, sorry if this topic is too simple for anybody, but I've googled quite some time and didn't really find anything useful, apart from this picture which just confirms my belief that /home/ and /proc/ can't be stacked: [image]

Comment: `/home/admin` is most likely the home directory of a user named `admin`.  It is not a special location relative to, say, `/home/joe`.

Answer (score 0):

/proc is a special filesystem which can give information about processes

For example (`$$` pid of current shell)

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$
cwd : symbolic link to current working directory
exe : symbolic link to process image
```